# Вопрос по laravel аутентификация Laravel Breeze

Tags: php, laravel

была установлена аутентификация Laravel Breeze, через какое-то время появилась ошибка Undefined variable $slot. Нашел решение заменить {{$slot}} на @yield('content'). Но на станице login отвалились стили[image: скрин]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добрый день, в laravel идет в коробке авторизация Laravel Breeze, В какой то момент появилась ошибка Undefined variable $slot, после гугления нашелся ответ {{$slot}} на @yield('content'), после этого страничка авторризации появилась но без стилей как например страничка регистрации. я посмотрел исходный код страничка login обернтута в @extends('layouts.app')@section('content'), а страничка register <x-guest-layout></x-guest-layout>  и вообще не врубаюсь как так произошло